# Direct deposit discrimination

Tags: discrimination

My job has refused to process direct deposits for the employees at my current store. Other locations have gotten their direct deposits with no issue. It's been months and I've reached out to my manager and payroll but nothing has changed. Is this a form of discrimination? What are my legal options?

Comment: welcome, @Tali! You could also ask at the forum workplace SE to get more input.

Answer (score 1):

If you believe that you are being treated differently from other employees because of your
race, color, national origin, religion, age, sex, gender, sexual orientation, pregnancy, physical or mental disability, you can file a [complaint with the EEOC](https://www.eeoc.gov/federal/fed_employees/filing_complaint.cfm). Location of employment is not a protected class, so you cannot sue because you don't get a benefit that employees at another store receive. That, at any rate, is US law. There may be a jurisdiction where place where you work is a protected class.